# what does precompute_distances do in sklearn kmeans method?

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am looking for the utility of the precompute_distances attribute:

```
    class sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, init=’k-means++’, n_init=10, 
    max_iter=300, tol=0.0001, precompute_distances=’auto’, verbose=0, 
    random_state=None, copy_x=True, n_jobs=1, algorithm=’auto’)
```

Which distances it precomputes?

Answer (score 6):

For each kmeans iteration, we need to find the closest cluster to each sample to perform labeling.  If `pre_compute == True`, this is done via `metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min()`.   If `pre_compute == False`, it is done via `cluster._k_means._assign_labels_array()`

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L618

The first method uses matrix operations, while the latter computes pairwise distances one pair at a time.   That's why `precompute = True` will be faster but will use more memory.

These minimum distances can not be cached between iterations because the kmeans centers will be changing .

Comment: What is the difference between 
     **cluster._k_means._assign_labels_array()** and **metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min()**?

Comment: _assign_labels_array() goes through each center for each sample.  pairwise_distances_argmin_min() does this all at once through a matrix operation or chunks of matrix operations

Comment: But where is used the pre-computation in **metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min()** when **pre_compute == True**?